# How should a pilot respond verbally to being cleared for takeoff?

Tags: air-traffic-control, takeoff, radio-communications

When ATC says "cleared for takeoff", what's the correct answer from the pilot?

Answer (score 27):

This is how [FAA recommends (PDF)](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/Presentations/12-02-RD179-RNAV_TPP_General_Info_example.pdf):

> A typical takeoff clearance may state, for example, “(Callsign) 123
>   RNAV to MPASS, Runway 26L, Cleared for Takeoff”.
>
> The expected pilot response is, “(Callsign) 123, RNAV to MPASS, Runway
>   26L, Cleared for Takeoff”.

Comment: It is probably worth adding that this is true of most ATC instructions : http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/288/3573

Comment: Also, if you're taking-off from an intersection of a long runway (many GA aircraft do), one should always try to mention the intersection for safety.

Comment: And the opposite too - if the majority of the traffic is taking off from an intersection, and you're taking off full length. Always a good idea to give ATC and others situational awareness.

Answer (score 21):

Same phraseology you're given: *cleared for takeoff* with your callsign, and if applicable, the runway or instructions ("turn left heading 200" for instance) given in the same transmission. Anything else is nonstandard.

Not *on the roll* nor *on the go* nor *cleared for departure* nor anything else, no matter how cool it sounded when somebody else said it on the radio.

Comment: Note, that bad phraseology regarding take-off clearance strongly contributed to [the worst aviation disaster in history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster). That's some good reason to stick to the standard.

Comment: @JanHudec where can I read more about that?

Comment: @JacobKrall [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster)

Comment: @JanHudec: Great tragedy, lots of lessons.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, you readback the runway identifier and the clearance - exactly like you receive it.

[image]

or

[image]

In case you get other instructions in connection with the takeoff clearance, you need to read those back as well.

[image]

Note that you should *not* read back any wind information given, since it is just that - an information - not a clearance or instruction.

*ICAO Document 9432, section 4.5*