# What is meant by the term "Code on request"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, general-aviation, clearance

I recently flew from a small airport under a Bravo shelf into the nearby Bravo airspace above. When I advised the ground controller that I was doing as such, he cleared me to taxi, then added the frequencies for the Bravo approach control and said "code on request". A moment later he came back with a discrete squawk code. I'm assuming "code on request" meant he had requested a squawk code from approach control and was waiting for the reply, am I correct? Is any response required by me? I got my PPL at a smaller airport and had never heard that before.

Comment: I haven't heard this exact terminology before, but your interpretation sounds correct to me!

Comment: Instances of this expression can be found online, like [here](http://capnjackon66.blogspot.fr/2008/09/flying-san-francisco-bay-tour.html): *After getting the ATIS, I call PAO ground and announce my intentions: "Palo Alto Ground, Cessna 96934 at Romeo 2-8 with Quebec for a Bay Tour." The usual response is taxi instruction and "code on request."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think you're correct although the phrasing is unusual. The usual phrase is "clearance on request", which is used for IFR departures as explained nicely in [this AOPA article](http://flighttraining.aopa.org/magazine/1998/September/199809_Flying_Safe_Checkride.html):

> Experienced instrument pilots know that when they call to request
>   their clearance, the controller may not yet have received it.
>   "Clearance on request" is ATC's way of politely saying "I don't have
>   it - I've requested it - you'll be the first to know when I get it!"

The only FAA reference for the phrase that I could find is buried in the glossary of the [Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Appendix-Glossary-Index.pdf):

> **Clearance on request.**  An IFR clearance not yet received  after filing a flight plan.

But as RalphJ [commented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21554/what-is-meant-by-the-term-code-on-request/21558?noredirect=1#comment48981_21558), if this is a VFR scenario and you needed a class B clearance and transponder code then I assume that the controller said "code on request" to let you know that he was waiting for a transponder code for you, as you assumed.

It wasn't an instruction as such so you could just acknowledge it with "Roger" or whatever. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/279/62) for more information on that.

Comment: He wasn't getting an IFR **clearance**, just a transponer code. Same concept, but a different thing the controller would get back from Approach to give to the pilot. The OP's understanding is correct.

Comment: I don't believe these are related - he's talking about a VFR departure, I believe.

Comment: @RalphJ That makes sense, the "code on request" phrase is nowhere to be found in any document, so I assume it's by analogy to "clearance on request". I'll update my answer.